# read binary file size of short stopped working since last week

Tags: c++, file, binary, sizeof

I had a program in C++ (Visual studio 2017) that worked perfectly fine until last week. 
Basically, I am reading a binary file:

I tried it with several files just to be sure that the problem is the code. But on the arrangement of the files nothing changed.

```
void getImageDimension(ifstream &inFile, unsigned int(&dim)[3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   
        inFile.read((char*)&dim[i], sizeof(short));
    }   
}
```

Until last week, got the correct dimensions and now (I think since the last windows update), it fails to read the file correctly. I tried it for several files, so the problem seems to be the code.

I should get the dimensions
`144 144 256`

But I get:
`34734224 144 32047317`

Does anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like the undefined behavior, somewhere in the code. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: What is the unholy mixing of types good for? You read 3 `short` into 3 half `int`s most probably. The 2 last bytes in the `int`s will be unchanged from before - if your `int` is 4 bytes and your `short` is 2 bytes which is pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

```
inFile.read((char*)&dim[i], sizeof(short));
```

does not look right to me. `&dim[i]` is of type `int*` and you are treating it like a `short*`. I suggest changing that to:

```
short temp;
inFile.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(short));
if ( inFile )
{
   // Reading into temp was successful. Use it.
   dim[i] = temp;
}
else
{
   // Do something with the error.
}
```